# Define Couchbase collection name based on property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have the below Repository that extends CrudRepository. Now based on a property called "scopeName", we need to inject the collection name using @Collection("collectionName").
So if the scope name is defined it should take the custom collection name. If not defined it should go with the default scope and default collection name. Any suggestion on how should this repository be defined?

```
public interface GlobalLockRepository extends CrudRepository<GlobalLock, String>,GlobalLockCustomRepository {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repositories that extend DynamicProxyable can select scopes and collections via the withScope(scopeName) and withCollection(collectionName) methods.

```
public interface AirportRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Airport, String>, DynamicProxyable<AirportRepository>{...}
...
List<Airport> airports = airportRepository.withScope("archived").findByName(iata);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.collections